# Create DialogFlow Agent using SDK

Tags: dialogflow-es

I want to create an Agent using the SDK of DialogFlow. I need create and destroy agents dynamically.

I have tried using the Java SDK and whitout success.

I tried generating the AgentsClient with the Java SDK V2.

First i make the connection to Storage

```
com.google.cloud.storage.Storage  storage = StorageOptions.newBuilder()
                .setCredentials(ServiceAccountCredentials.fromStream(new FileInputStream("key.json")))
                .build().getService();
```

Afthe that i had tried this:

```
AgentsClient client = AgentsClient.create();
```

But not work like i understood. The requiremente is that using the SDK can create a new agent not get some existing agent.

Comment: Can you update your question to include how you tried to do it and what errors or problems you had while doing so? It isn't clear what your problem is or what your question is. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Done @Prisoner Thanks for ur help